# Discord.js V14 || SlashCommand || Invalid from body

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I coded this command and fixed all the errors but don't understand why this error shows up, I've had commands in the past without these options.
Node.JS V19.3.0

C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
options[3][APPLICATION_COMMAND_OPTIONS_REQUIRED_INVALID]: Required options must be placed before non-required options
at handleErrors (C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1021:23)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:862:14)
at async REST.request (C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
at async ApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\crazy\Codeing\CrazyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:171:18) {
requestBody: {
files: undefined,
json: [
{
name: 'announcement',
name_localizations: undefined,
description: 'Sends a embed message in a channel.',
nsfw: undefined,
description_localizations: undefined,
type: undefined,
options: [
{
type: 8,
name: 'ping-role',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Pings the role.',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: true,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
},
{
type: 7,
name: 'channel',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Channel that the embed message gets sent in.',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: true,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
},
{
type: 3,
name: 'title',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Title of the embed.',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: false,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
},
{
type: 3,
name: 'description',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Sets the description of the embed.',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: true,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
},
{
type: 11,
name: 'image',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Sends a image in the embed.',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: false,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
},
{
type: 3,
name: 'footer',
name_localizations: undefined,
name_localized: undefined,
description: 'Set the footer of the embed',
description_localizations: undefined,
description_localized: undefined,
required: false,
autocomplete: undefined,
choices: undefined,
options: undefined,
channel_types: undefined,
min_value: undefined,
max_value: undefined,
min_length: undefined,
max_length: undefined
}
],
default_member_permissions: '8',
dm_permission: undefined
}
]
},
rawError: {
code: 50035,
errors: {
options: { '3': { _errors: [ [Object] ] } }
},
message: 'Invalid Form Body'
},
code: 50035,
status: 400,
method: 'PUT',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1123448402450059436/commands'
}

My code:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("announcement")
    .setDescription("Sends a embed message in a channel.")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)

// |#################################|
// |          Role Ping              |
// |#################################|
    .addRoleOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("ping-role")
        .setDescription("Pings the role.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// |#################################|
// |        Channel Option           |
// |#################################|
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("Channel that the embed message gets sent in.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// |#################################|
// |         Embed Options           |
// |#################################|

// ##### Title #####
    .addStringOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("title")
        .setDescription("Title of the embed.")
        .setRequired(false)
    )

// #### Description ####
    .addStringOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("description")
        .setDescription("Sets the description of the embed.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// #### Image ####
    .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("image")
        .setDescription("Sends a image in the embed.")
        .setRequired(false)
    )

// #### Footer ####
    .addStringOption((option) => 
    option
        .setName("footer")
        .setDescription("Set the footer of the embed")
        .setRequired(false)
    )
,
```

Comment: You should use the search function and read the error messages. As I mentioned in my linked answer, you can't have required options after non-required ones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is in the error.

> Invalid Form Body
> options[3][APPLICATION_COMMAND_OPTIONS_REQUIRED_INVALID]: **Required
> options must be placed before non-required options**

You must place all required options before optional ones.
The 4th option (`description`) is required, but the third (`title`) is not.

You have to put the `description` option before the `title` option:

```
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName("announcement")
.setDescription("Sends a embed message in a channel.")
.setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)

// |#################################|
// |          Role Ping              |
// |#################################|
    .addRoleOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("ping-role")
        .setDescription("Pings the role.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// |#################################|
// |        Channel Option           |
// |#################################|
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("Channel that the embed message gets sent in.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// |#################################|
// |         Embed Options           |
// |#################################|

// #### Description ####
    .addStringOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("description")
        .setDescription("Sets the description of the embed.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

// ##### Title #####
    .addStringOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("title")
        .setDescription("Title of the embed.")
        .setRequired(false)
    )

// #### Image ####
    .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
    option
        .setName("image")
        .setDescription("Sends a image in the embed.")
        .setRequired(false)
    )

// #### Footer ####
    .addStringOption((option) => 
    option
        .setName("footer")
        .setDescription("Set the footer of the embed")
        .setRequired(false)
    )
,
```